# Unbestreitbare Nominalphrase in der indirekte Rede

Tags: indirect-speech

In dem Film *Das Leben der Anderen* gibt es einen Schriftsteller namens Dreyman, der fragt: »Kann jemand, der diese Musik gehört hat, wirklich gehört hat, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein?«

Ich habe Probleme mit der Nominalphrase »jemand, der diese Musik gehört hat«: Wie schreibt man das als indirekte Rede? Es ist keine Behauptung, sondern eine Definition; anders gesagt, es hat keinen Wahrheitswert, ist nicht fraglich. Also, welcher der Folgenden ist richtig?

> 1. Dreyman fragt, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört **hat**, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein könne.
> 2. Dreyman fragt, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört **habe**, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein könne.

Und wenn Dreyman stattdessen *behauptet* hätte, »**Niemand**, der diese Musik wirklich gehört hat, kann noch ein schlechter Mensch sein.« – dann?

> 1. Dreyman sagt, dass niemand, der diese Musik gehört **hat**, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein könne.
> 2. Dreyman sagt, dass niemand, der diese Musik gehört **habe**, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein könne.

Und warum?

Comment: Nehmen wir an, die Eigenschaftsbeschreibung wäre statt des Relativsatzes ein Adjektiv, z.B. "blond". Würdest du dann in der Indirekten Rede "angeblich" oder "seiner Meinung nach" davorschreiben?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Konjunktivierung in der indirekten Rede soll ja eine Distanz zum Gesagten ausdrücken, und den Gehalt des Gesagten dem Zitierten zuordnen, und nicht dem Sprecher.

Der propositionale Gehalt (du nennst es den Wahrheitswert) der Aussage Dreymanns steckt nicht in der Prämisse (Jemand hat diese Musik gehört), sondern in der Folgerung (der kann kein schlechter Mensch sein). Daher würde ich auch nur diesen Teil in den Konjunktiv setzen:

> Dreyman sagt, dass jemand, der diese Musik gehört **hat**, kein schlechter Mensch sein **könne**.

Ist das auslösende Verb *fragen*, wird also vom Zitierten gar keine Behauptung aufgestellt, von der man sich als Sprecher ggf. distanzieren möchte - die Frage hat gar keinen propositionalen Gehalt oder Wahrheitswert. Daher ist meiner Auffassung nach eine solche Distanzierung überhaupt nicht nötig, es geht also auch völlig unproblematisch zweimaliger Indikativ:

> Dreyman fragt, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört **hat**, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein **kann**.

Die Verwendung des Konjunktivs hat allerdings gegenüber dem Indikativ den Vorteil, dass man sich über die korrekte Zeitenfolge keine Gedanken machen muss. Der Indikativ stellt einen vor die Wahl ob man

> Dreyman fragte, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört hat, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein **kann**.

schreibt oder (vielleicht korrekter, je nach Kontext)

> Dreyman fragte, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört hat, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein **konnte**.

(also, ob er Zeitpunkt, an dem die Frage gestellt wurde, Einfluss auf die Frage hat, ob sie damals, heute oder generell gemeint war). Der Konjunktiv zieht sich diesbezüglich mit

> Dreyman fragte, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört **hat**, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein **könne**.

die das offen lässt, ganz einfach aus der Affäre.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so - der Nebensatz ist nicht Teil einer bestreitbaren Aussage. Bin aber nicht ganz bei dir, was den zweimaligen Indikativ angeht - das ist in der Umgangssprache praktikabel, in einem Buch oder einem Aufsatz würde ich Konjunktiv sehen wollen.

Comment: Drehen wir den Satz mal: Er fragte, "kann ein blonder Mensch böse sein". In indirekter Rede würde man nicht sagen: *Er fragte, ob ein **angeblich** blonder Mensch böse sein könne*.

Comment: Der Konjunktiv in einer indirekten Frage sorgt auch gleichzeitig für eine passende Zeitenfolge. Denn "Kann ein blonder Mensch böse sein" läßt sich sinnvoll in den Indikativ übersetzen zu "Er fragte, ob ein blonder Mensch böse sein kann" oder "Er fragte, ob ein blonder Mensch böse sein konnte" (sprich, ob die damalige Frage damals, heute, oder generell gelten sollte) - "Er fragte, ob ein blonder Mensch böse sein könne" entledigt einen dieses Dilemmas.

Comment: Nur zur Info: [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) ist für Posts gedacht, bei denen die Community gemeinschaftlich eine Antwort über edits generieren und ergänzen soll. Das wäre z.B. eine Liste. Um fehlende Fakten zu ergänzen braucht es das nicht, jeder kann, darf und vor allem **soll** editieren. Das ist das Wesen aller StackExchange Seiten.

Answer (score 2):

Der "Wahrheitswert" ist nicht das Einzige, wovon man sich in der indirekten Rede distanzieren kann. Was, wenn man die Art der Kategorisierung ablehnt? Oder ein anderes Verständnis von »hören« hat?

Wenn zum Beispiel jemand die Frage zum Ausgang eines Essays macht:

> Dreyman fragt, ob jemand, der diese Musik gehört hat, noch ein schlechter Mensch sein könne. Aber wer hat diese sogenannte Musik überhaupt "gehört"? Ist es zulässig, Hörvermögen und Menschlichkeit derart zu verkoppeln? ... *etc* ...

Hier wäre der Konjunktiv meines Erachtens konsequenter gewesen, denn durch den Indikativ »gehört hat« macht man sich immer noch die Zuschreibung zueigen. Deutlicher wird das, wenn der Subjektsatz besonders anstößige (z.B. diskriminierende) Zuschreibungen enthält.

> Er fragt, ob jemand, der eine grüne Hautfarbe hat, ein guter Mensch sein könne.

Eine solche Wiedergabe klingt für mich, als die Kategorisierung nach »grüner Hautfarbe« selbst nicht infrage gestellt werden.

In gewisser Weise ähnlich sind Zusätze, die nicht direkt den Wahrheitswert betreffen:

> Sie: »Hat er schon wieder diese Musik gehört?«
>
> Sie fragte, ob er schon wieder jene Musik gehört habe.

Auch hier reicht der Konjunktiv »gehört habe« nicht unbedingt aus, um sich vollständig von der Aussage zu distanzieren. Man würde u.U. das »schon wieder« in Anführungszeichen setzen, um nicht nahezulegen, dass man selbst glaubt, "er" hätte die Musik schon einmal gehört.

Comment: Guter Punkt! +1

Comment: Ich akzeptiere die andere Antwort, weil sie kompletter ist, aber diese ist ganz aufklärend und ein ausgezeichneter Zusatzpunkt – danke sehr.